# Android ListView - RSSPro app has stopped working?

Tags: android, android-emulator, rss, android-listview

I've followed [this tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/#comments) but when I try to run the application I get "Unfortunately RSSPro has stopped."

This is my code for the RSSProActivity:

```
package com.android.rss;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RSSProActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> headlines;
    ArrayList<String> links;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


     // Initializing instance variables
        headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00059.warnings_vic.xml");

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

                /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
                 * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
                 * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
                 * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
                 * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
                 *
                 * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
                 */
            boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if (insideItem)
                            headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        if (insideItem)
                            links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                    }
                }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                    insideItem=false;
                }

                eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Binding data
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
           try {
               return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               return null;
             }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String positions = (String) links.get(position);
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(positions);
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

My main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat messages:

```
05-21 19:44:40.528: D/dalvikvm(528): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-21 19:44:41.716: I/dalvikvm(528): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-21 19:44:41.726: I/dalvikvm(528): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-21 19:44:41.946: D/dalvikvm(528): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 3% free 9136K/9347K, paused 113ms
05-21 19:44:41.956: I/dalvikvm-heap(528): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.904MB for 960016-byte allocation
05-21 19:44:42.056: D/dalvikvm(528): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 10072K/10311K, paused 6ms+14ms
05-21 19:44:42.176: D/dalvikvm(528): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 10072K/10311K, paused 38ms
05-21 19:44:42.196: I/dalvikvm-heap(528): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.963MB for 2160016-byte allocation
05-21 19:44:42.217: I/dalvikvm(528): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-21 19:44:42.306: I/dalvikvm(528): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-21 19:44:42.316: D/dalvikvm(528): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 12181K/12423K, paused 3ms+4ms
05-21 19:44:42.526: D/gralloc_goldfish(528): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-21 19:44:48.076: I/dalvikvm(528): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-21 19:44:48.206: D/AndroidRuntime(528): Shutting down VM
05-21 19:44:48.206: W/dalvikvm(528): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-21 19:44:48.216: I/dalvikvm(528): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.rss/com.android.rss.RSSProActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.getInputStream(RSSProActivity.java:92)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.onCreate(RSSProActivity.java:48)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-21 19:44:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  ... 11 more
05-21 19:44:48.616: I/dalvikvm(528): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-21 19:44:48.708: I/dalvikvm(528): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-21 19:44:49.116: I/dalvikvm(528): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-21 19:44:49.206: I/dalvikvm(528): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-21 19:44:49.436: I/dalvikvm(528): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-21 19:44:49.476: I/dalvikvm(528): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-21 19:44:56.997: I/Process(528): Sending signal. PID: 528 SIG: 9
```

I'm currently using the SDK 15 version (Android 4.0.3). My codes can be compiled in Eclipse but couldn't run on the emulator. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can u post ur logcat files here...

Comment: in ur Main.xml file u r using Listview but in your code u din't take any reference for listview take reference for listview and set ur adapter to Listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) because of retrieving the XML in main thread. Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform the fetching and parsing of XML in background. A sample can be found in: [Read RSS in background, using AsyncTask](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/read-rss-in-background-using-asynctask.html)

Comment: ya this seems to be the problem, I put a try catch block on it and it can run now. It's weird because the author of the tutorial can get it run. Thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: The tutorial is written prior to the release of Honeycomb SDK. As you can see from the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` documentation, application targeting SDK versions prior to Honeycomb are allowed to perform network on main thread, but it will get terminated by ANR error if the access takes longer than expected response time.